# MacBook Pro on any wifi stays connected but won't load pages after a few minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

This started happening a couple weeks ago and I am at a loss. The issue has been happening on every wifi I have connected tom: my phone via tethering, my university's guest and student wifi, and third party wifi at a coffee shop.

This is what happens: After a reboot and connecting to any wifi it will work for between 30 seconds and 5 minutes, then it still says that it is connected but no web pages will load (tested in safari and chrome.)

What I've tried:

• Reseting PRAM

• Reseting SMC

• Removing all known wifi networks

• Creating another user account (same issue)

• Changing DNS IP addresses

• Reinstalling the OS (while preserving user data)

• Tethering to phone's network via BlueTooth with wifi off (same issue, stops working after a few minutes)

And finally I have tried installing windows 10 with bootcamp. When booted into windows the issue does not appear, so because of this it seems to me that it is not a hardware issue. So I am really lost, does anyone have any other ideas I could try?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running and which MacBook Pro?  Also, can you provide the output of `ifconfig en1` when the issue occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a VPN client I had installed a while ago, I didn't think of it because it hadn't been running for quite a while but uninstalling it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same. Sometimes cable connected to wifi card becomes loose which can cause this issue.

Can you check once what RSSI you are getting when you are scanning the the Wi-Fi network? Usually macOS at -70 dBm RSSI shows very less connectivity but windows works fine.

1. Click on "Apple" icon.
2. Select "About the mac"
3. One window will pop-up then select "System Report"
4. One another window will pop-up. Select "Wi-Fi" under "Network" option.

you will get all the network list. All the scanned network will have a field "Signal/Noise", where you will get your RSSI value.